# New way to change button label in jquery mobile 1.4

Tags: jquery-mobile, button, label

Before, it was done this way

```
$("label[for='buttonid'] .ui-btn-text").html('newtext');
```

What is the new way? Button comments here http://jquerymobile.com/upgrade-guide/1.4/ do not seem to cover this issue.

Comment: `$("button").text("new text").button("refresh")` this works on `button` and `input` type button tags only.

Comment: Is there anything more general, which applies to radiobuttons, too? In the meantime, I grouped more buttons into a radiobutton.
I have come up with 
    $('label[for=thisbutton]').html('new text')
} 
but strangely, sometimes it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#buttonID').find(".ui-btn").text("newText");
```